# Setting up Multi-Site LSTM

Tags: keras, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have set up my data like so,

```
time 1: [location1, location2] [temp1 1, temp2 1]
time 2: [location1, location2] [temp1 2, temp2 2]
```

Obviously it doesn't look exactly like this but just to show how it was set up. When I input this into my LSTM it says "valueError: setting an array element with a sequence". Any suggestions on the set up? I can post more code if that's helpful

Here's a look at what the first value of the x training input looks like

```
[array([array([0.69793787, 0.65924992, 0.7340775 , 0.6900613 , 0.71091108,
        0.70743612])], dtype=object)
```

There are six locations so six temperatures